# Replacing a number in a array if duplicates are found with a random numbe

Tags: arrays, duplicates

I am trying to generate an array of specified size, fill it with random integers and then iterate through the array to check that there are no duplicates. I am having some inconsistencies when testing this. Wondering if it can be done using nested for loops or whether a better approach is suggested?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int size = 10;
        int[] newArray = InitializeArrayWithNoDuplicates(size);
          for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
        {
          Console.WriteLine( newArray[i]);
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }

    static Random rng = new Random();

    public static int[] InitializeArrayWithNoDuplicates(int size)
    {
        int minValue = 1;
        int maxValue = 10; 
        int[] array = new int[size] ;

        for (int i = 0; i <array.Length; i++)
        {
           array[i] = rng.Next(minValue, maxValue);

              for (int j = i+1; j < array.Length-1; j++)
                    if (array[i] == array[j])
                     {
                    array[i] = rng.Next(minValue, maxValue);
                     }
           }return array;
    } 
}
```

Comment: It's 'quite hard' to find 10 random integer numbers with no duplicates in the range 1..10 ;) And if you ever increase the size of your array without increasing the range allowed, the program will be unable to complete the task!

Comment: You fill your array from `0` towards `length-1`, right? But, once you devise a new `i`-th item, you compare it to the uninitialized part of the array at indices `i+1` through `array.length-1`, and not to those already filled at `0` through `i-1`....! How do you expect it to assure uniqueness of values?

Comment: @CiaPan - It is *not* a hard problem. Not even a little bit. Every program that simulates a deck of cards solves this exact problem, and with the "problem size" over 5 times as large.  OP's approach is wrong, but that's not the same as the problem being hard.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger If I saw a program that 'deals' cards by randomly guessing them and discarding duplicates I would stop cooperation with its author and write the program myself. It's next to bogosort, IMO. The much faster, one-pass and no-duplicate-check way to choose K cards is shuffle a deck and take first K items. Or generate K random indices (with duplicates allowed) for decreasing deck and in each iteration remove a card at generated index.

Comment: @CiaPan - What part of "OP's approach is wrong" do you not understand?  You've merely described a different algorithm for "find[ing] [n] random ... numbers with no duplicates in the range 1..[n]".  If you want to be arrogant, try being correct first.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger I already said, what wrong is; please read again. Second, it's comparing new data with no-data-yet, which yields useless results. First, it's requiring 10 unique integer values in the range 1..9.

Comment: @CiaPan - That's nice.  But none of it has anything to do with anything I said.  Maybe I'm not the one who needs to reread.

Comment: I commented the problem itself and the proposed implementation; you started discussion about my comments. I can't help if your discussion appeared unrelated to what I said. EOT.

Comment: @CCodez Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45819433/733637) expanded.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first parameter in `Next(minValue, maxValue)` is an inclusive lower bound, while the second one is exclusive bound, which means the returned value shall be greater than or equal to `minValue` and less than `maxValue`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx

Hence, for

```
    int minValue = 1;
    int maxValue = 10;
```

the generator can only return nine different values, `1` through `9`, and you are UNABLE to fill the `10` items `array[]` with them and make them unique.

You must either assume shorter array, or allow bigger span for random values.
Or allow duplicates...

For quite short sets of data the fastest approach is filling an array and generating a permutation of it. Suppose you want to put numbers 1..N into an N-item array.  Prepare the array first:

```
    int[] array = new int[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
        array[i] = i+1;
```

then permute it. This shuffling algo iterates from `i==N-1` down to `1` and in each step it chooses an item to put at index `i`:

```
    for (int i = N-1; i > 0; --i)
    {
        int j = rng.Next (0, i+1);
        swap (array[j], array[i]);    // exchange values
    }
```

Please note that in each iteration we take a random index `j` from `0` to `i` *inclusive*, so it is possible that `j==i` which means the value of `array[i]` stays where it is. This way in each iteration we draw a new number from those not drawn yet to put at consecutive places, as a result we obtain each possible permutation of `array` with equal probability (assumed the random number generator `Next` method always returns values with uniform distribution over the interval defined by its arguments).
The loop terminates when `i` reaches `0` – there's no item below index `0` we could choose to swap with `array[0]`.

If the span of your data is a bit longer than the required array length, but both values are quite small – say, you need 80 values out of 100 – you can make an array to keep the whole set (that is 100 items), fill it, shuffle it and then drop un-needed 20.
If you choose to drop items from the *beginning* of the array, you can also abandon last 20 steps of shuffling.

For a very large set of possible values this would be ineffective. Suppose you need a random sequence of 500 values out of a hundred million – would you like to allocate, fill and shuffle 100,000,000-items array to get just 500 values? Certainly not!
Assuming for the sake of simplicity that your data space is again an interval of integers, you can build a self-balancing BST of integers. Initially the tree is empty.
Then you iterate this step 500 times: generate a random number K and seek it in the tree; if it's not there, you add it and it becomes one of your output values. If you find the number K, it is a duplicate and you re-iterate the step, drawing another K from `rng`.
The probability of re-selecting the same number is qute low, in the last iteration it's 5 hundred to 100 million, that is 1/200,000. Anyway, it *can* happen.

With a structure like self-balancing BST, seeking for the value can be limited to a logarithm of N, so for N output values you perform N iterations, and each time you make up to log(N) steps to detect a possible duplicate, hence the whole time complexity is about N·log(N).

Other structures may give even faster duplicate detection, thus leading to lower execution time.

Answer (score 0):

Your duplicate-elimination logic won't work.  Consider the situation where the array starts `[1, 2, ...]` and you're setting the 3rd element.  You randomly generate a `2`.

Then you start your inner loop.  When `j == 1` the comparison shows no problem.  When `j == 2` you see that your new value would be a dup, so you reroll.  But your reroll *could* be a 1 (dup of the 1st element, which you don't check again) or a 2 (dup of the 2nd element, which you don't check again).

More generally, this approach is very inefficient.  For this particular case (placing all 10 numbers form 1 to 10 in a random order) something like this might be better:

- Create a list L of the available values (each number 1 thru 10)
- While L is not empty

  - Generate a random number N between 1 and the size of L
  - Set the next open element of your output array to the Nth element of L
  - Remove the Nth element from L

There are many ways to implement this approach.  Don't be afraid of the overhead of maintaining suitable data structures; it's nothing compared to the algorithmic cost of an algorithm with nested loops and random/potentially unlimited retries, which is where your original approach is heading.

Comment: Although your advice is correct, the underlying analysis is flawed. Please note that for `array == [1, 2, ...]` and `i==2` the code presented will NOT compare a new `array[i]` to `array[0]`, because the inner loop starts at `j=i+1`, that's at index 3, and goes forward.

Comment: @CiaPan : I'm not getting hung up on code typos when the algorithm is the problem.  The code's intent was clear, and this analysis addresses that intent.

Comment: Thanks, I realise the logic now. For this problem, I was given an initial range between 1 to 45, how ever I restricted to trouble shoot the algorithm quicker, I realise now the errors in this part of the logic. Thanks for noticing the indexing is incorrect, I have ammended this and still having problems. I will attempt using your approach  Mark Adelsberger. 
Thanks